# Troubleshooting error message 'Name 'COLOR_GRAY2RGB' is not defined' while plotting images in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

```
def plot_from_img_path(rows,columns,list_img_path,list_mask_path):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
    for i in range(1,rows*columns +1):
        fig.add_subplot(rows,columns,i)
        img_path=list_img_path[i]
        mask_path=list_mask_path[i]
        image=cv2.imread(img_path)
        image=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2,COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
        mask=cv2.imread(mask_path)
        plt.imshow(image)
        plt.imshow(mask,alpha=0.4)
    plt.show()
```

When I try to run the next command

```
plot_from_img_path(3, 3 , image_filenames_train, mask_files )
```

it gives error saying name `'COLOR_GRAY2RGB' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Try `image=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)`
You had a faulty comma.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because you have not defined or imported the library to the variable "COLOR_GRAY2RGB". One you my example where I have used it and it is working is.

```
import cv2

color_img = cv2.cvtColor(gray_img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
```